# Issues with Xcode 11 - "INT is not convertible to CGFloat?"

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

Please see my code below. I have tried a few things but nothing seem to help. The one thing I did notice is that if I comment out line# 28, the code works fine but if I keep line# 28 as is, I keep getting the error.

I have tried change it to:

```
HStack(alignment:.center, spacing: CGFloat(50))
```

But this hasn't worked either. Please help 
Thanks in advance for taking the time to look into this.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  UdemyCourse
//
//  Created by Karan Singh on 10/29/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Karan Singh. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack(alignment:.center, spacing: CGFloat(50)) {
                Image("Karan").resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 120, alignment: .center)

            VStack{
                Text(verbatim: "Karan Singh").font(.title).foregroundColor(.black).bold()
                Text(verbatim: "Customer Success")
            }
        }

            Divider()

            TextField($text, placeholder: Text(verbatim: "Enter Text"))

            ButtonView(title: "Login", clickAction: {
                print("Click to Login")
})

//struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
//    static var previews: some View {
//        ContentView()
//    }
//}
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should note Xcode will complain about errors in the wrong place so the error that you are getting might have nothing to do with what is actually wrong.

---

Looking at your code there seems to be a couple of mistakes. Unless you have written your own components for `TextField` and `ButtonView` (which you should have included in your code example if you did) then the error appear to be with them.

Firstly the `TextField`, it takes the following parameters in its simplest form:

```
TextField(<title: StringProtocol>, text: Binding<String>)
```

which is different from what you have written (I also cannot find a `TextField` that matches the overloads that you have provided). So you should update your `TextField` to be:

```
TextField("Enter text", text: $text)
```

Secondly there is no component called `ButtonView` so I would assume that you are meaning to use `Button`. It's parameters are:

```
Button(action: () -> Void, label: () -> _)
```

So you should update your `Button` to be:

```
Button(action: {
    print("Click to login")
}) {
    Text(verbatim: "Login")
}
```

If we put it all together (swapping out the image for a system named image as I do not have a picture of you), we get the following which compiles without error:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.center, spacing: 50) {
                Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)

                VStack {
                    Text(verbatim: "Karan Singh")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .bold()
                    Text(verbatim: "Customer Success")
                }

                Divider()

                TextField("Enter text", text: $text)


                Button(action: {
                    print("Click to login")
                }) {
                    Text(verbatim: "Login")
                }

            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Note: that the `ContentView_Previews` should be outside of your `ContentView` struct.